# Visual Studio 2013 Can't Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS 2013 C/C++ solution that has 3 projects.  A project is a static library, B project is a static library, and C project is a DLL using A and B and other source code.

I can't enable the deploy checkbox in the configuration manager.  I've done it on several solutions before but for some reason this solution/projects won't let me check the checkbox highlighted in the photo.

[image]

What controls being able to enable/disable that checkbox?  When searching on MSDN and SO I found many references to not being able to deploy but they were web projects and the difference between deployment and publishing seemed to be the issue.  I haven't found anything regarding when you can't check the box for a C/C++ DLL.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that in project settings ( for C ) two lines were swapped.  ( path to output directory was in the wrong spot - highlighted lines ) Why VS can't give me an error for this is unknown and super annoying.
[image]